# Command line not recongnising commands

Tags: command

I am super new to command line and am following this yt video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBBWVgE0ewk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGDV6SnbINlVUd0o2xT4JbMu

I am having trouble cd and .. to directories as the above tutorial does. I get thrown an error saying that the directory does not exist or the ..is not a recognized command.

This is really putting me off cl as its only the first step towards using cl.

[My command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjN2H.jpg)

Comment: You need to show exactly what you have entered in the cmd window and the resulting errors. Otherwise, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I have edited the post of the commands I typed into the cl. The first line I tried to search for the folder Desktop and tried to jump to the folder above using the .. command.

Comment: **Desktop** directory exists under your user folder, not under **c:\windows\system32**. **..** refers to the parent directory, so it's not a command. You probably wanted to use `cd ..`. That would move you up to **c:\windows**. Try to find a better learning resource, e.g. https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm

Comment: Your correct I wasn't in the correct directory! Thanks I will take a look at the link you shared!